# Connection string for oracle 11g on remote server to visual studio?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, oracle11g, tnsnames

I have installed the oracle on windows server 2012 which is a webserver 
and trying to connect oracle with visual studio 2010 on windows 7.

I have installed `odp with odac tool` for vs2010.

I am adding new data connection and providing the data source as:

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=my_server_ip)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))
```

and then specificing the userid and password but it is not connecting and showing error of tns timeout.

[image: timeout]

What's wrong i have done and how could i remotely access oracle 11g from my pc.

Comment: Do you have a tbsnames.ora file?   This is typically done via ODBC ( or whatever it is called by MS these days.  When the server loads the oci.dll file and attempts to make the connection it passes in the TNS NAME and then the oracle client resolves the name and makes the connection.

Comment: @FlyingGuy: You don't need any `tnsnames.ora` file when you use the full connection string as given in question. This file is used only to provide a kind of shortcut for the full connection string.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the DB with other tools, e.g. SQL*Plus or do you reach it by `tnsping`? Perhaps your firewall blocks `my_server_ip:1521`.

Comment: i have forword the port 1521 on server and also allowed in firewall. The only problem is in connecting.